# How do you reset real number count?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

This is simple code for add number. I press 10 times.

```
- (IBAction)Button1 {

NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", count++];
counter.text = numValue;
[numValue release];
{
```

I clicked Reset button and start pressing Button1. What happen to Zero?

```
- (IBAction)Reset {
Counter.text = nil;
}
```

How do I reset back to real value zero?

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
- (IBAction)Reset {
   count = 0;
   counter.text = @"0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) resetNum

{

//actual variable
count = 0;

//just for cosmetics
Counter.text = @"0";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) Reset 

{

count = 0;

Counter.text = @"0";

}
```